# jQuery each looping inside variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, variables, each

I have issue with this chunk of code,

```
var sourceArray = ['facebook', 'instagram', 'youtube', 'twitter', 'linkedin', 'vk', 'google+'];

var utmMediumContent = '<select name="utm-source" id="i-utm-source" class="builder-input">'+
$.each(sourceArray, function(index,value){
    console.log ('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
    return ('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
})
+'</select>';

console.log(utmMediumContent);
```

first console.log return exactly, what I want `<option value="facebook">facebook</option>` etc.,

but second console.log return just select and values in array - facebook, instagram, youtube etc.

```
<select name="utm-source" id="i-utm-source" class="builder-input">facebook,instagram,youtube,twitter,linkedin,vk,google+</select>
```

I would appreciate any help or solution how to loop inside variable if it is possible.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you should do it. You should append the `select` and the `options` to an array. See the working snippet:

```js
var sourceArray = ['facebook', 'instagram', 'youtube', 'twitter', 'linkedin', 'vk', 'google+'];

var utmMediumContent = [];
utmMediumContent += '<select name="utm-source" id="i-utm-source" class="builder-input">';
  $.each(sourceArray, function(index, value) {
    //console.log('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
    utmMediumContent += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
  });
utmMediumContent += '</select>';
console.log(utmMediumContent);
$(utmMediumContent).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning you can construct the element with concatenation:

```
  utmMediumContent  += '<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>';
});
utmMediumContent += '</select>';
```